Union of connected closure with nonempty intersection is connected
I am having trouble showing the following:

Let $A$ and $B$ be connected sets of some topological space $X$ and $A\cap \mathop{Cl}B\neq \emptyset$, where $\mathop{Cl}B$ is the closure of $B$. Then show that $A\cup B$ is connected.

First of all, we know that $B$ connected $\implies$ $\mathop{Cl}B$ connected.
It would also be (relatively) easy to show the connectedness of $A\cup B$ given $A\cap B\neq \emptyset$, which also implies, here, that $A\cup \mathop{Cl}B$ is connected.
Hence, here it suffices to show that $A\cap B\neq \emptyset$. However, I cannot see how the given closure condition can guarantee that.

It is not true that $A \cap B$ is non empty. Take $A=(0,1],B=(1,2)$.

This question is similar to: Union of connected subspaces $A$ and $B$ of $X$ such that $A\cap \overline{B} \ne \varnothing$ is connected. Found using the search engine of this site: https://math.stackexchange.com/search?q=Union+is+connected

See also https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1971562/union-of-connected-subsets-x-y-is-connected-if-overlinex-cap-y-neq-var

@copper.hat This is a really helpful example, thanks! :)

You sholud mention that $A,B$ are subsets of a topological space $X$.

@AnneBauval I was just explaining how this question was different in the kind of answer I needed. I am very happy with its accepted answer, and I agree with it being closed. In the meantime, actually, I just came back to see the alternative answer of one you linked, which used continuous functions, that I couldn't yet use at the time I asked. Also, I felt uncomfortable discussing in anything more pronounced than a comment why it is "different"---I considered my kind of answer somewhat petty and an irrelevant clutter to a future scholar (or even future me). Now all is as it should be.Thanks! :)

Here is an outline of a proof. Suppose $A \cup B$ is not connected, then there are $U,V$ open, non empty disjoint sets such that $A \cup B \subset U \cup V$. Without loss of generality we can assume that $A \subset U, B \subset V$. By assumption, there is some $x \in A \cap \overline{B}$, and so $x \in U$. Since $U$ is open, $U \cap B$ is non empty and hence we have a contradiction.

It was smelling like a duplicate, so better link to an older post, and if your answer is really new, post it over there.

@copper.hat Thanks! Here, where do $U, V$ live? Are they a (the?) separation of $A\cup B$, in which case $A=U$, $B=V$ and I cannot see why $U\cap B$ must be non-empty. If they live in $X\supset A\cup \bar B$, then why is $U\cap B$ a contradiction? I guess you use somewhere that some non-empty open neighbourhood must intersect $B$?

@Janis if $c$ is in the closure of $B$ then any open set containing $x$ must intersect $B$, otherwise $x$ could not be in the closure. This is from the definition of closure.

@Janis A set is not connected iff  if it is the union of two disjoint non empty open sets.

@copper.hat Thanks. Let me focus on my confusion. Let $\Omega$ be the respective topology. Then by definition of connectedness there have to be $U',V'\in \Omega_{A\cup B}$ disjoint with $U'\cup V'=A\cup B$. Their openness in the relative topology implies the existence of $U,V\in \Omega_X$, with $U\supset U'$, $V\supset V'$, bu definition of openness in the relative topology. But I don't see what forces $U$ and $V$ themselves to be disjoint, unless $X$ was also connected, which we are not guaranteed. If $U$ and $V$ are not indeed disjoint, then $U\cap B$ is no contradiction. What am I missing?

@copper.hat Thanks again :) But, in your answer $U$ and $V$ do not form such a union, but only a cover of the union.

@Janis Just let $X' = A \cup \overline{B}$ and work in the $\Omega_{X'}$ topology.

@copper.hat Oh my god! I see it now! Thanks, thanks a LOT!

@Janis Connectedness is surprisingly subtle, and the subtleties often glossed over.
